# Imprimir array list condición java

Tags: java

Buen dia tengo una lista donde imprimo con el siguiente código:

```
lista.forEach(row -> {
   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row)); 
 });
```

y me imprime esa lista la información de la siguiente manera:

```
[126, LIZETT, Salida, 21/Oct/2021, 0:30]
[126, LIZETT, Entrada, 22/Oct/2021, 9:00]
[128, DENISS, Salida, 21/Oct/2021, 9:10]
```

yo quiero imprimir de la siguiente manera aqui es donde no se como hacerle, quiero que si hay fechas iguales me agrupe la información quedando así:

```
                          21/Oct/2021                            22/Oct/2021
     
LIZETT    Entrada: 09:00       Salida: 20:21.
DENISSE                                                          Salida: 09:10.
```

aun no tengo idea como lograr este resultado.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class CrearXml 
{ 
   
    public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    String folderPath = "/Users/javier.solis/Desktop/";
    String fileName = "checador.xml";
    String xmlFile = folderPath + fileName;         
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder;
    try
    /// gets the main nodes in the config and saves them to a list
    {
        dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(xmlFile);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        //System.out.println("Root element is:" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
        NodeList mainList = doc.getElementsByTagName("check");
        List<String[]> lista = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int temp = 0; temp < mainList.getLength(); temp++)
        {
            Node mainNode = mainList.item(temp);
            Element eElement = (Element) mainNode;
            lista.add(new String[] {doc.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagName("noempleado").item(temp).getTextContent()
                    ,doc.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagName("nombre").item(temp).getTextContent()
                    ,doc.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagName("registro").item(temp).getTextContent()
                    ,doc.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagName("fecha").item(temp).getTextContent()
                    ,doc.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagName("hora").item(temp).getTextContent()
                    ,doc.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagName("diferencia").item(temp).getTextContent()
            });
        }
        
        
        //int repe = 0;
        //int k = 0;
        lista.forEach(row -> {
          System.out.println("**" + Arrays.toString(row));
             //System.out.println(A.get(1)[4]); 
            //System.out.println(A.get(1)[3]); 
        });
        /*List<String[]> Repetido = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int x = 0; x < lista.size(); x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < lista.size() && !Repetido.contains(lista.get(x)); y++) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, lista.get(x)[3] + "***" + lista.get(y)[3]);
                if (lista.get(x)[3].equals(lista.get(y)[3])) {
                    repe +=1;
                    //System.out.println(lista.get(y));
                }
            }
            if(repe>0){
                //Repetido.add(k,lista.get(x)[3]);
                Repetido.add(new String[] {lista.get(x)[3]
                    
                });
                //System.out.println("EL ELEMENTO " + Repetido.get(x)[3]  + " SE REPITE "+ repe);
                k++;
            }else{
                
            }
            repe=0;
        }
        Repetido.forEach(row -> {
            System.out.println("**" + Arrays.toString(row));
             //System.out.println(A.get(1)[4]); 
            //System.out.println(A.get(1)[3]); 
        });
        //System.out.println(A);
        //System.out.println("Fin del Proceso, Verificar");
        /*for (int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++) {
           for (int  x= 0; x < A.size(); x++) {
         //System.out.println("\t\t"+ A.get(i)[0] + "\t\t"+ A.get(i)[1] + "\t\t" + A.get(i)[2] + "\t\t" + A.get(i)[3] + "\t\t" + A.get(i)[4]);
                System.out.println("\t\t"+ A.get(i)[3] + "\t\t"+ A.get(x)[3]);  
                if (A.get(i)[3]==A.get(x)[3]){
                    
                    //System.out.println("\t\t"+ A.get(i)[3] + "\t\t"+ A.get(x)[3]);  
                                    
                }else{
                    
                }
           }
        }*/
         
    }
    catch(SAXException | ParserConfigurationException | IOException e1)
    {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

asi es como tengo el código no se si me puede alguien orientar igual a la mejor estoy mal desde un principio, estoy un poco perdido en el ultimo paso. Quiero leer mi xml y se presente en reporte en pantalla las condiciones son que si en la etiqueta fecha son diferente son columnas diferentes con datos de nombre y registro en su columna de fecha

Comment: agrega el código de la lista que imprimes para que puedan replicar tu ejemplo

Comment: listo ya lo agregue @valle50

Comment: Lo agregaste como respuesta, debes agregarlo a tu pregunta, editalo de nuevo pero ponlo en tu pregunta.

Comment: creo que ya @valle50 checa si estoy bien a tu petición por favor

Comment: hora si creo ya quedo si te sirve así ? @valle50